# GUI keyword confusion

Tags: 10.10, desktop-environments

Ive been using linux for some time, and ive never quite got my head around the various keywords attached to the GUI.

I think i understand the difference between the likes of KDE and Gnome - They are collections of applications and other software that make up a given gui environment. However a quick read through any vaguely technical linux websites will reveal terms like:

- Murrine
- Clearlooks
- GTK
- Beryl
- Metacity
- Window manager

Which if im honest, i have no real idea what they mean and how they all relate to each other. Can anybody clarify?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may confuse you further, but I'm going to add a few more words to that list. I've tried to highlight the buzzwords while I paint a picture of how things fit together.

### Window managers

It might sounds silly but window managers manage your windows. They sit right next to the X Server (that controls what gets sent to hardware) and decrees how windows are painted to the desktop (itself a type of window).

As well as managing where the window goes, how big it is, if it's above something else, it's also responsible for decorations. Most window managers defer to another application called a **window decorator**. These decide how your window borders look, as well as giving you some options (resizing, window buttons, etc).

**Metacity** (a window manager) has its own window decorator built-in but other window decorators you might see around include `gtk-window-decorator` (used by Compiz by default) and **Emerald**, spawned from Beryl which can do slightly fancier things at the cost of CPU cycles.

**Beryl**, **Metacity**, **Compiz** are all **window managers**. Beryl was a fork of the original Compiz. It advanced well ahead of Compiz and was eventually merged back to form a project called Compiz-Fusion. Compiz-Fusion has now (AFAIK) been renamed back to Compiz although both names still apply to the same, modern project.

### Graphical Toolkits

GTK+ (aka GTK) is a graphical toolkit that developers use to create rich, graphical user interfaces. Using tools like Glade, they decide how an application should look by placing GTK+ controls (eg a button) on a window, using further arrangement technologies like Glade.

GTK+ also contains several sub-projects like **Cairo** and **Pango**, two graphics libraries that programmers can use to draw things inside their applications. In turn these libraries can reach out to more libraries to help them render things (like using **Freetype** to render text).

GTK+ development libraries are a bottomless pit. I could literally spend all day listing them out but it won't really help you. So I won't.

Part how these controls are rendered to the screen involves a **theme engine**. Each engine has *n* themes available for it and the user picks one in their preferences. That theme uses its engine to let controls render themselves onto the screen. **Clearlooks** and **Murrine** are both engines and they both have themes named after them, as well as a ton of other themes knocking around the internet.

The stack would look something like this, from bottom to top:

- GTK+ Control
- GTK+ Engine and its GTK+ Theme
- Application (X Server Client)
- Window Decorator
- Window Manager (aka compositor)
- X Window Server
- Hardware

That's ultra-simplified (I've just explained a compositing system) and a lot of that stuff can happen in altered orders, often running parallel rather than on top or beneath another layer... But it should give you an idea of how things get from code to screen.

**Qt** is another graphical toolkit which is very common in KDE applications. It has its own theming engines, themes and controls that similar to GTK+. They're not interchangable and require heavy code overhauls to port from one toolkit to the other.

Answer (score 1):

Metacity is a window manager. Window managers gives you the interesting decorations around the windows (title bar, close button, etc) as well as managing windows. GTK is a widget set which gives you the buttons, labels, checkboxs, etc in the actual windows. Clearlooks is a theme and Beryl is like compiz.